# Rendering HTML on TextView does not work

Tags: android

I have the following String containing HTML tags in my strings.xml:

```
<string name="login_title">Ihr Zugang für <br /> <u>zusätzliche</u> <br /> Business Inhalte</string>
```

The layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:maxWidth="686dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/login_textview_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/textcolorprimary"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And i inflate the `TextView` and set the text in a dialog:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.activity.getLayoutInflater();

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.activity);

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_login, null);

    TextView textViewTitle = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.login_textview_title);
    textViewTitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(this.getResources().getString(R.string.login_title)));

    builder.setView(rootView);
    builder.setCancelable(false);

    return builder.create();
}
```

And the result is the following:

[image]

So the html gets totally ignored. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

Replace all `<` inside the string with `&lt;`